# How to move cursor to the end of the line in a cell in Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, ms-office

For example,

In any text editor:

**Command+right arrow** will put your cursor to the Right of the line
**Command+left arrow** will move your cursor to the Left of the line

Is there an equivalent keybord shortcut for this in Excel for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FN + Left Arrow
FN + Right Arrow

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know that non-standard answer. Does anyone know if there's a setting to allow the normal Mac answer (command left/right arrow) to work?

Comment: @JohnM +1. Also the Option+Left/Right to jump words does not work in Excel. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what version of Excel you're using however see the Moving and scrolling in a sheet or workbook section of [Keyboard shortcuts in Excel 2016 for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Excel-2016-for-Mac-acf5419e-1f87-444d-962f-4e951a658ccd).

[image: Moving and scrolling in a sheet or workbook]

Comment: its Office For Mac 2011...updated above too